# Publisher, how to set different prices for different regions (USD, €, etc..)

Tags: android, console, publish

i just can't find it anywhere, so i'd appreciate and help on this :=)

I read about it, and it should be possible, for instance,

I want to set a Dollar price for an App@ 3,99 USD,
while the price in Euros is just 2,49 (about) €

So that the values fit, and there isn't something like 3,74 USD ;=) (maybe it frightens some customers ;=P)

Would be great if anyone could tell me where to set this in the Android Developer Console?

Thanks a lot,
best regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe this feature is not yet available for you.  It is currently only available in the US.  Below excerpts are taken from my documentation:

```
Over the next few months, Android Market will be transitioning towards offering 
applications priced in the buyer's home currency, rather than the merchant's 
(developer's) home currency. This feature will be rolling out in stages, 
country by country. As an Android Market merchant, you will be notified by email 
when we are ready to release the feature in your locale and action is required from 
you -- at that time you must visit the Developer Console and and set prices for your 
apps in all available currencies.
```

If you have not received an email, it is not available in your market yet.

```
Availability:
This feature is not available in all countries and currencies at this time. Currently     
only US merchants are able to set prices in EUR, CAD, CHF, DKK, GBP, NOK and SEK currencies.
```

Comment: only US merchants are able to set prices <-- that's it, thanks a lot for the teaching ;) totally skipped this line. best regards :) thanks once again :)